# Setting up a RAID 5 with expansion in the future in mind

Tags: raid, network-attached-storage

I am setting up a NAS box, but money is a bit short right now.  I am planning on getting the box up and running with a boot drive, then 3 for a RAID 5 config with some lower end drives.

I was reading online about a bunch of the complications that can arise from people not setting it up right, and couldn't get a feeling of exactly how hard/feasible it would be.

So,

1. Is it possible to upgrade (replace a drive with a bigger/faster one) and/or add drives (without wiping, and rebuilding)?
2. How risky is it to do this with data that isn't backed up (because of sheer volume)?
3. Any tips/advice I should follow to set up a best case in the future to allow upgrades?

Note, I'm really between a RAID 5, and a RAID 01.  Would this be easier to upgrade a RAID 01?

Comment: What is your use case for this NAS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of a single boot disk and 3 disks in RAID 5, consider 4 disks in RAID 10. This is both faster and safer. You do not want your NAS to go down if the single boot disk fails.
Additionally, RAID 5 has poor write performance and does not rebuild reliably on large, terabyte-denominated volumes, especially when you are using inexpensive drives.

Answers:

1. Replacing a disk with a larger one: Not with a standard RAID controller. Some vendors (e.g. Drobo) have proprietary
   RAID implementations that support adding disks of dissimilar sizes, etc., but traditional RAID remains far more dependable. If you want to play with something dynamic
   and innovative, I would suggest ZFS. *Added in response to TomTom's observation that only half of question #1 had been answered:* Expanding an array by adding disks of the *same size* as existing array members is supported by many enterprise RAID controllers. Larger disks will be treated as though they are no larger than existing disks. This may be unsupported by low-end/integrated RAID devices. Check the documentation for your specific controller.
2. No. RAID is never an excuse for failing to have a backup and a DR plan. Having "too much data" is also not an excuse for failing to back up; however, it may be an opportunity to assess whether any significant portion of your data can be classified as genuinely unimportant.
3. With consumer grade 2TB SATA drives costing only $80 each in 2011, and enterprise-grade 2TB SAS drives costing only $240, you can add 4TB of usable RAID 10 capacity for $320 (consumer-grade) or $960 (enterprise-grade) if you have sufficient bays and connectors. That's a very cheap incremental upgrade path.

Comment: The problem with the backups is the fact that this is meant as the main storage hub (where I will backup my computers to), where would I put a backup of this?

Comment: "Noit with a standard raid controller"? Joking? Seriously? You use 10 year old stuff? All - areca, adaptec, 3ware - suppot capacity expandion online these days. For quite some time.

Comment: Increasing capacity by adding additional drives of the same size is a separate question from "can i replace a drive with a bigger/faster one." It appears that I erred in answering only one of the two questions.

Comment: Be very cautious about using workstation grade HD's in a RAID array - they aren't built for the vibration problems you encounter by putting a lot of drives next to each other.  You will have a much higher failure rate, and your overall performance will suffer.  (This is only to amend the data in comment 3 to encourage purchasing slightly more expensive, but correctly designed drives for the purpose you have).

Comment: @mazzzzz: Where to back up? That's up to you. If you are planning to store backups *and* live data on this array, be sure to create a separate "backup" share or folder so that you can exclude it from your backups of the live data. In poorly managed disk-to-disk backup scenarios, people can inadvertently make backups of backups of backups and then wonder where all their space went.

Comment: @Miles So your suggestion is to create a backup of a RAID in the RAID?  Seems counter intuitive (if the RAID dies, how would I get to the backups of the RAID?).  Unless you mean compress the backups extremely small, and put it on a separate RAID/drive..  Could you clarify a bit more (if you want, your answer is already accepted)?

Comment: Not at all. I was merely suggesting that if the bulk of what you're storing on the NAS is workstation backups and only a portion of what you're storing is live data, then you may decide that you don't need to back up the workstation backups (if you can accept data loss in the unlikely event that both a workstation and the NAS were to fail concurrently).

Answer (score 2):

Re 1: depends. On technology used, which you say nothing about. I use Adaptec raid controllers, and thy do that, without pulling the raid.

Re 2: depends how much you value your data. I copy all data to another server or two with large slow drives.

Re 3: Except investing oney into a decent raid controller and making sure you have the hardware layout in place for that? For example, what is expansion for you? I run a 24 slow server for that reason (to allow expansion),  rack units. Now i start filling up the last 8... the next server will be a 4 rack unit 72 bay machine allowing me to put in 72 discs. But then, this costs (just th case) around 3000 USD, so "cheap" and "expansion" are very relative terms, you know.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question 1:

Yes, it is feasible to expand a RAID 5 by either adding more disks or by replacing existing disks with larger disks.  "The maximum number of drives in a RAID 5 redundancy group is theoretically unlimited."  [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_5).  Ask yourself first, however, whether your filesystem will support this operation.  Adding larger disks needs to be done across the entire RAID before you will be able to recognize the benefit.

Regarding question 2:

I would characterize a RAID reconstruction as inherently risky.  I do it all the time but I never do it without careful thought and a bit of nervousness.

Regarding question 3:

Look at LVM.  Also, consider using an external JBOD (just a bunch of disks) instead of trying to cram all the drives into a standard chassis.  Disks are relatively cheap.  Go SATA.  You can get 3TB SATA drives for $150.  Buy the best RAID card you can afford.  I've had good luck with LSI and Adaptec.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Is it possible to upgrade (replace a drive with a bigger/faster one) 
> and/or add drives (without wiping, and  rebuilding)?
> ```

That depends on the precise bit of kit you buy. It's a device specific issue.

> ```
> How risky is it to do this with data that isn't backed up (because of
> sheer volume)?
> ```

Lets be clear about something - RAID is not a backup, period. Anyone who stores data on a drive system without backing it up is a fool. That's *without even considering* the potential for issues with changing drives and expanding the array. If you change the properties of a RAID array without backing up any important data you store on it first then you must be mad.

> ```
> Any tips/advice I should follow to set up a best case in the future to
> allow upgrades?
> ```

1. Carefully research the product you
   wish to buy and make sure it
   supports this functionality.
2. Plan
   for backups *anyway*, never mind
   during array expansion.
3. Be wary of
   special offers on "End of Life" NAS
   systems, which may not support
   newer, larger hard disks, thus
   limiting your expansion potential.